# Do repeated dereferences increase time complexity?

Tags: java, time-complexity

Suppose I have an if statement like the following

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    map.put(nums[i], i);
}
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    int complement = target - nums[i];
    if (map.containsKey(complement) && map.get(complement) != i) {
        return new int[] { i, map.get(complement) };
    }
}
```

If the if statement evaluates to true, would `map.get(complement)` get run twice by the program, making it more advantageous to use a variable before this if statement to assign the result of this dereference, or would the compiler/heap (or something) keep this value in memory so that multiple statements like this only get evaluated once? If it gets evaluated twice, would that increase time complexity for something like a hash map here, or do lookups only take O(1) time anyway so it doesn't really matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lookup on `HashMap` takes `O(1)`.
For time complexity constant factors **don't matter**, so if you execute a `O(1)` call twice it will still only be `O(1)` since `O(2) = O(1)`. So something like

```
map.get(complement)
map.get(complement)
map.get(complement)
map.get(complement)
```

Is still in `O(1)` because you only execute it a constant amount of times, independent of your input variables.

Java itself doesn't *optimize* the `map.get(complement)` call, the map could have changed between both calls. At least I don't know a compiler that does, but maybe there are some that analyze your code that deep.

---

The loop itself is in `O(n)` for `n = nums.length` because you have at least the worst case (where the map does not contain the key) where you iterate it completely, yielding `O(n)` for `n = nums.length`. Probably also in a typical case since your `complement` could be anywhere, probably there is no pattern that would make it such that it only yields constant iterations.

And the loop above runs in `O(n)` too because it executes `O(1)` statements `n`-times.

Comment: It's a hash map. Nothing "amortized". Average, expected. The "amortized" thingies is for Union-Find and immutable queue analysis. (I didn't downvote, no clue what's going on here)

Comment: Correct, but the put will be amortized due to possible rehashs.

Comment: Down-vote: Question is about the `if` statement, not the entire loop. It's about whether `containsKey()` + `get()` changes the Big-O.

Comment: Don't I answer this? The `if` still stays in `O(1)` (first paragraph).

Comment: @Zabuza Yes, but rehash is only relevant while putting stuff into hashmap, not for lookups. That's why I complained about "amortized".

Comment: But second paragraph is wrong, for the question, and you don't indicate that you're talking about something else.

Comment: @Andreas Really? I don't see it like that. I just give additional information after fully answering the question in the first paragraph.

Comment: @Andreas I either don't understand what you're asking, or I don't understand what's wrong with Zabuza's answer.

Comment: *"in the worst case"*? Sure. But also in the *typical* case. --- *"loop above runs in O(n) all the time"* Not true. In the *best* case, it only runs O(1). --- Sure, you're trying to answer more, but you just ended up muddling the waters, making things confusing to the people new to Big-O, so it's not helping.

Comment: But you have now improved the answer enough for me to remove down-vote. Not enough (yet) for an up-vote from me, though.

Comment: @Andreas Just curious, how does the above loop not run in `O(n)`? It executes `O(1)` calls `n`-times, in any case imo.

Comment: *"For the loop, in the worst case [...] you iterate it completely, yielding O(n)"* Here, you're talking about worst case of the loop, iterating `n` times, i.e. O(n). Best case for the loop is that `if` statement is true on first iteration, resulting in O(1) for the *loop*. Average is O(n) too and maybe that's what you meant by *"O(n) all the time"*, but the way you phrased it, is just ... misleading, at the very least.

Comment: @Andreas With "*above loop*" I meant the first loop, that puts elements. It has no `if`, it always needs `O(n)`. And since OP didn't asked for case-analysis I assumed the usual analysis technique, that is to include all possibilities (including the worst case) for a general correct bound. That is, worst case dominates general analysis with no case-restrictions. At least that where my thoughts when I wrote it.

Comment: @Zabuza I accept that, and it's a very good point, and since my comments finally got you to write the answer to reflect what was in your thoughts, and hence clear the confusion the previous versions of the answer caused, you now get my up-vote.

Answer (score 1):

As the compiler/JIT has no way to know whether two invocations to a method will yield the same result there is no way to optimize the calls away. Given that any program may be multithreaded it may even be so that without proper synchronization the map is modified between the two calls and the result of the `get` returns a *different* object.

Because the `get` method will return `null` if you ask for a key that doesn't exist the code can be rewritten as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
   int complement = target - nums[i];
   Integer value = map.get(complement);

   if (value != null && value != i) {
       return new int[] { i, value };
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the time complexity does not change: the time required for every possible execution path through the `if`-statement can be upper-bounded by the time required for a lookup, multiplied with factor 3, plus some overhead for all the other constant time-calculations. `O(3 * constant_1 + constant_2)` is asymptotically still just `O(1)` for positive constants.

Since there are no guarantees for referential transparency, the compiler will not optimize the three lookups away.

However, the concrete implementations of the hash map could theoretically (possibly, in the future releases) maintain a cache with pre-computed hash codes and their position in the internally stored array for keys that have been recently been passed to `contains` method.

Another factor to consider is how your hardware handles memory access. It could be, with a sufficiently clever memory manager, that the content of the hash map is "warm" when it is accessed the second time, so that the second and third access don't matter all that much.

Conclusion: no, the asymptotic runtime does not change. Make it correct first. Then profile it. Then optimize it, if necessary.